# Как исправить ошибку в строчке?

Tags: python

```
def is_prime(x):
  return not sum(1 for v in range(2, x // 2 + 1) if x % v == 0) if x >= 2 else False
```

такой текст ошибки:

```
File "main.py", line 2
  return not sum(1 for v in range(2, x // 2 + 1) if x % v == 0) if x >= 2 else False
^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: У вас какой-то непонятный символ перед return. Удалите все и проставьте отступы заново.

Comment: Как выглядит у меня... копирую код функции, получаю ошибку.. Удаляю все перед return вписывая 4 пробела (или tab) и все работает... Используемый символ U+2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете [этот символ](https://codepoints.net/U+2003) вместо [пробела](https://codepoints.net/U+0020) или [символа табуляции](https://codepoints.net/U+0009), замените первые два символа на пробелы или таб.